# How do you read the File Properties of a file found via GetFiles function?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a collection of executables, their directories, and their version numbers displayed in a GridView like so:

```
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\PathExample")
For Each foundFile As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim foundFileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(foundFile.ToString)
    'Dim foundFileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(foundFile.Directory.ToString)
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(foundFileInfo, foundFile.Directory, foundFile)
Next foundFile
```

The GridView will successfully show the executable name, and the directory in their respective columns, however, I get thrown an error:

**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Console.exe'**

Console.exe is in fact an existing file, and it's able to obtain the directory and executable name, and store it in the GridView, it's ONLY when I try to get the file version info that it starts throwing this error.

Am I using the wrong function?
I basically need to be able to read any line from this menu:
[FileProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFOd.png)

I need to be able to read each property individually, like getting just the File Version, or Copyright info, or Last-Modified date, etc. and storing that into a variable to be placed in one of the columns in the GridView.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with the code:

- `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` expects the full path of the file. Don't use `foundFile.ToString`. Instead, use `foundFile.FullName`.
- `foundFile` is a FileInfo object. You shouldn't add it directly to a DataGridView cell. Select the appropriate property instead. You probably want `foundFile.Name` (or perhaps `.FullName`).
- Similarly, `foundFileInfo` is an object of type `FileVersionInfo`. You should use a specific property to display in the cell.

Assuming you want the file description, directory path, and file name (respectively) in the cells, your code should look something like this:

```
For Each foundFile As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim foundFileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(foundFile.FullName)
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(foundFileInfo.FileDescription, foundFile.DirectoryName, foundFile.Name)
Next
```

You can use `foundFileInfo` to get other info like the file version, copyright, etc. See the available properties under the [FileVersionInfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties).